# Sequelize One to Many Association Update won't work

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

This is how my two models are connected:

```
DebitInvoice.hasMany(DebitInvoiceProduct, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    foreignKey: 'invoice_serial'
});
DebitInvoiceProduct.belongsTo(DebitInvoice,{
    foreignKey: 'serial'
});
```

I am trying to update `DebitInvoice` and while doing so I also need to delete previous `DebitInvoiceProduct` rows and add new ones.
That is why I am using `onUpdate: 'CASCADE'`.
I am trying with this code:

```
const result = await DebitInvoice.update({
    invoice_for: 'data',
    invoice_date: 'data',
    /* other fields */
    DebitInvoiceProducts: productList,
},{
    where: {serial: 'data'}
},
    include: [DebitInvoiceProduct]
);
```

I can update `DebitInvoice` fields but nothing happening at `DebitInvoiceProduct`

Where I am doing wrong or What should I do to get what I needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` does not have `include` option so you either need to call `setDebitInvoiceProducts` for each `DebitInvoice` model instance or call `destroy` and `create` on `DebitInvoiceProducts`:

```js
const invoices = await DebitInvoice.findAll({
    where: {serial: 'data'}
});
for (const invoice of invoices) {
  const invoiceProducts = productList.filter(x => <here are conditions to get product list for a certain invoice>)
  await invoice.setDebitInvoiceProducts(invoiceProducts)
}
```

OR

```js
const invoices = await DebitInvoice.findAll({
    where: {serial: 'data'}
});
await DebitInvoiceProducts.destroy({
  where: {
    invoiceId: {
      [Op.in]: invoices.map(x => x.id)
    }
  }
})
for (const invoice of invoices) {
  await DebitInvoiceProducts.bulkCreate(productList.map(x => ({
    productId: x.id,
    invoiceId: invoice.id
  })))
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and not having any problem. But, it would be great to have this feature in sequelize